# Output from SQLite database into columns should display values, but just shows default "TextView"

Tags: java, android-studio

I'm trying to output three columns from my SQLite database and have them show on a "table" in my Android app.

While I can run my query and get the correct number of cells to populate, for some reason my code doesn't put the values from the query in them and so it keeps displaying a table that just says "TextView" in every row.

To do this I first run a query in my class with all my queries and have called this method `getListContents()`.

I am then creating two layouts:

Layout 1 is called `view_player_history.xml` and is just a list view in a linear layout.

Layout 2 is called `list_adapter_view.xml` and is again a linear layout, but this time there are three text views's to give the three columns for my data.

I then create three different classes:

**User Class:** Here I am defining all my columns and returning the relevant data.

```
public class User {
private String Year;
private String Club;
private String Apps;

public User(String year, String club, String apps) {
    Year = year;
    Club = club;
    Apps = apps;
}

public String getYear() {
    return Year;
}

public String getClub() {
    return Club;
}

public String getApps() {
    return Apps;
}
}
```

**ViewPlayerHistoryContents class:** Here I'm accessing my SQL database to pull the data and add it to the list to display

```
public class ViewPlayerHistoryContents extends AppCompatActivity {

DatabaseAccess myDB;
ArrayList<User> userList;
ListView listView;
User user;

@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.view_player_history);

    myDB = new DatabaseAccess(this);

    userList = new ArrayList<>();
    Cursor data = myDB.getListContents();
    int numRows = data.getCount();

    while (data.moveToNext()){
        user = new User(data.getString(0), data.getString(1), data.getString(2));
        userList.add(user);
    }

    com.example.transfergame.ThreeClass adapter = new com.example.transfergame.ThreeClass(this, R.layout.list_adapter_view, userList);
    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);


}
}
```

**Three Class:** Here I am trying to assign it to the different text views so it displays in my columns

```
public class ThreeClass extends ArrayAdapter<User> {

private LayoutInflater mInflator;
private ArrayList<User> users;
private int mViewResourceId;

public ThreeClass (Context context, int textViewResourceId, ArrayList<User> users){
    super(context, textViewResourceId, users);
    this.users = users;
    mInflator = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    mViewResourceId = textViewResourceId;
}
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parents) {
    convertView = mInflator.inflate(mViewResourceId,null);

    User user = users.get(position);

    TextView Year = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textYear);
    TextView Club = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textClub);
    TextView Apps = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textApps);

    return convertView;
}
}
```

But for some reason, it doesn't seem to be assigning the values. I know the rest of it is working fine because as I mentioned it always outputs the correct number of rows in my ListView. It just doesn't update the text. Because of this, there is also no error message, as nothing fails.

Is there a typo that is stopping the values being assigned to each TextView?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you haven't actually assigned the values to each of your TextViews. You've just initialized the variables.

You need to add

```
Year.setText(user.getYear());
Club.setText(user.getClub());
Apps.setText(user.getApps());
```

so you set the text for Year, Club and Apps.